# TensorFlow: Checking whether a pre-trained model is successfully restored?

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, computer-vision, deep-learning

I am currently running a `managed_session()` using a supervisor to test the performance of the official inception-resnet-v2 model checkpoint file (offered by Google) on a few dog images (Border Collie images that I took from Google images). However I am seeing a very strange behavior: The losses for a managed session run by a supervisor with an `init_fn` that takes a saver that restores all the variables from the checkpoint file and another managed session run by a supervisor without an `init_fn` at all gives almost an entirely similar loss (around 6). What is funny is that the supervisor with no `init_fn` even has a lesser loss of under 6 (around 5.9 to be specifc), while the one with `init_fn` has a loss slightly over 6. I understand that even if the loss may be random at times, how could the performance of both be so similar?

I am wary that my model might be reusing the same weights from a previous session (just a guess), and so I used `tf.reset_default_graph()` at the very start of my code. Also, I also made sure to clear the log directory where the supervisor might look for checkpoints from earlier sessions. Yet, the performance is so similar. Is it just that the model performing too well with or without a checkpoint file? All the images have been successfully predicted with a label of 232 (border collie).

Just to be sure, I did an initial prediction before any of my training started. The non-restored model has an initial prediction of class 411 (apron), while the restored model has the correct prediction of 232. But I am not sure if this is indicative that my restored model is working - how do I definitively check whether the model is successfully restored?

Also, what is considered as an acceptable loss for a softmax_cross_entropy loss? I think a value of around 6 may be too high, but I can't find the official loss obtained by the Google paper on the inception-resnet-v2 model.

Here are some details about my model:
1. Due the my GPU memory limitations, I could only run a batch size of 6. I included only 8 images to test.

2. The non-restored model has an initial loss of around 8, while the restored one has an initial model of around 6.

The main difference in my code for both supervisors is this:

```
#For the supervisor with init_fn
variables_to_restore = slim.get_variables_to_restore()
saver = tf.train.Saver(variables_to_restore)
def restore_fn(sess):
    saver.restore(sess, checkpoint_file)
sv = tf.train.Supervisor(logdir = log_dir, summary_op = None, init_fn = restore_fn)

#For the supervisor without init_fn
sv = tf.train.Supervisor(logdir = log_dir, summary_op = None)
```